# A sum related to the theta function

Tags: summation, special-functions, theta-functions

I am interested in the serie
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(2n+1)e^{-tn(n+1)}$$
for something I am working on. Wolfram alpha gets stuck on this problem, but it gives the following result for a closely related summation:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-tn(n+1)} = \frac{\vartheta_2(0,e^{-t})}{2e^{-\frac{t}{4}}}$$
where $\vartheta_2$ is a Jacobi theta function. I was hoping anyone here would have some idea about how to proceed for this problem, or, even better, a solution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: An approximate value [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3230790/305862).

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks, that's helpful.

Comment: It is an **incomplete theta function**, this is because the complete theta function is $\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty(2n+1)e^{-tn(n+1)}$ and the sum over negative $n$ cancel with the sum over positive $n$. Incomplete theta functions lack most of the nice properties of complete theta functions.

Comment: Another reference for an approximate value [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4141663/305862) obtained (as the other one by asking formula) searching tool [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/)

Comment: If there were alternating signs we could use the standard identity $\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n(2n+1)q^{n(n+1)/2}=\prod_{n\geq 1}(1-q^n)^3$. I doubt if your sum has a nice closed form.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh That's very interesting, as I have also a case where I have alternating signs. Do you have a reference for this identity? And do you know if it leads to a closed form?

Comment: The identity is proved in my [blog post](https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2013/06/congruence-properties-of-partitions-part-1.html?m=0). It is a consequence of Jacobi triple product identity. Closed form is available in terms of elliptic integrals.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Nice, thank you very much!

Comment: You may be interested in [OEIS sequence A198954](https://oeis.org/A198954) which has a generating function very close to your infinite sum.